# Static vs dynamic linking of modules in Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, dynamic-linking, static-linking

Why are most of the modules in Android statically liked to the kernel, rather than loading them dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a non modular kernel is a common practice in embedded systems. Unlike a Desktop/Server Machine, on a phone, the hardware is not likely to change, most of them do not have USB ports and hence there's no need to have kernel features/hardware support be loaded in form of modules.

You know the filesystem you want to use, the network interfaces that you need support for etc and all of this can be built into the kernel instead of having them loaded dynamically.

Criteria I use to decide what goes into kernel and what is built as modules - If there are features (like network interface support/filesystem support) which you need all the time, then include them in the kernel. If there are features which you would need only at certain points (like netfilter modules) build them as modules

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, the downside this approach is that, the boot time increases due to a larger kernel. Wouldn't it be better to place the modules in sysstem/lib/modules and 'insmod' them when they are required?

Comment: i have updated my answer to answer your question partly, regarding boot time, if its a module to support a filesystem, you would have to load it eventually anyway, so doesn't really make a difference whether you load it during boot time or as a module

Comment: Actually you can boot an embedded system faster using modules, even for things you know you'll need eventually.  eg just build what is needed to get the display working and userspace running into the kernel so you can show a GUI, then in the background load your networking modules etc.  This makes the system seem responsive sooner even if its not really totally booted for a little longer.